# Create dictionary from folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a dictionary storing list of directories of a folder and the folder name.

Here is my code:

```
#initialize empty dict
my_dict = {}
my_dict['filename'] = []
my_dict['label'] = []

# store data:
for file in os.listdir(folder):
  with open(os.path.join(folder, file),'r', encoding='utf-8') as review:
    my_dict['filename'].append(file)
    my_dict['folder'].append(folder)

print(my_dict)
```

My code returns

`{'filename': ['0_3.txt', '1_1.txt', '2_1.txt', '3_4.txt', '4_4.txt'],  'folder': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}`

But desired output is:

`[{'filename' : '0_3.txt', 'folder' : '0'}, {'filename' : 1_1.txt', 'folder' : 0}, ...] ...`

Could you help?

Comment: The keys in a dictionary are unique, so you cannot have that output. One alternative is to create a list of dictionaries or tuples

Comment: You can't have the same key multiple times.

Comment: Maybe you meant `[{'filename' : '0_3.txt', 'folder' : '0'}, {'filename' : 1_1.txt', 'folder' : 0}, ...]`?

Comment: that's it! I'll edit the question

Comment: Update your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, dictionary keys must be unique. Based on your comment, it looks like you want a list containing multiple dictionaries, which you can construct like this, appending a new dict for each file:

```
files_info = []

for file in os.listdir(folder):
    # ...
    files_info.append({"filename": file, "folder": folder})

print(files_info)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can in each iterate create `dict` and append to `list` like below:

```
>>> out = []
>>> for file in os.listdir(folder):
...    dct = {}
...    with open(os.path.join(folder, file),'r', encoding='utf-8') as review:
...        dct['filename'] = (file)
...        dct['folder'] = (folder)
...        out.append(dct)
        
>>> out
[{'filename' : '0_3.txt', 'folder' : '0'}, {'filename' : 1_1.txt', 'folder' : 0}, ...]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your desired output violates the working model of python dictionary.
You see, dictionaries work in *{key:value}* pair model, and every key must be unique if you are to pair it with a value that you'd want to look up later.

See below in bold? your keys are repeating.

{'**filename**' : '0_3.txt', '**folder**' : '0', '**filename**' : 1_1.txt', '**folder**' : 0}

Comment: The user is looking for a way to do this in python. I would try adding some example code that would help the user achieve his example output.